# VirtualBox crashes (illegal instruction at...)

Tags: virtualbox

Recently (within the last week) I've gotten crashes of my Ubuntu 14.04 VirtualBox.

It might be associated with use of the clipboard, but I'm not sure about that. I edit in both gedit and QtCreator and switch between the two. USB problems too.

Only thing I can find in the log is

```
220:48:33.744796 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002)  
aIID={f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}  
aComponent={SessionMachine}  
aText={The machine is not mutable or saved (state is Stopping)},  
preserve=false aResultDetail=0
```

Comment: The VM isn't in a state where it can be loaded, or it's not stopped completely yet.  You can't start the machine, as such.  (Basically, your VM is broken, which in turn crashes VirtualBox)

Comment: I've usually been running for 30 minutes and I'm not trying to stop: just editing (or sometimes compiling).

Comment: NEVER edit your VM when it's running.  It will break things.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was unclear. I'm editing source files in QtCreator and gedit on the VM. I am not editing the vm. It is common for me to select text in gedit and paste it into QtCreator. The other common activity involves running bitbake from the command line and plugging and unplugging USB drives. I'm not sure what triggers the crashes. I doubt that debugging in VisualStudio will help, but that is the only option I'm given.

Comment: More data: when I build, the processor has trouble doing "other things". In particular, when I'm in QtCreator, it grays out sometimes. When I insert a USB drive and try to add it to my VB, it shows it as selected in the Devices/USB list, but it does not mount. Eventually, Windows "steals" it back, leaving it unavailable to the VB when the build finally finishes. I think this might be associated with the problem. I'm going to try to avoid inserting the USB while the machine is busy and see if that reduces the instances of crashing.